# Spanish chracter and some spaceial chracter not allowed in Imagmagick

Tags: imagemagick

Spanish chracter and some spaceial chracter not allowed in Imagmagick when creating images from pdf.
There is showing error message "**no decode delegate for this image**".
Can i ignore that text while creating images from pdf.

Any solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

`convert -list configure | grep -i "DELEGATES"`

What does that mean?

```
**convert -list configure** - displays your imagemagick configuration

**grep -i "DELEGATES"** - takes the results from above and does a case insensitive search for what you're looking for, in this case, you're looking for the section marked DELEGATES
```

This should return all of the packages that you need in order to run your command.

Using your favorite package manage ( apt, yum,brew, etc ), install those packages ( including their development packages ), then try again.

Here is a thread you can check out, where someone had a very similar issue:

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22488

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still not working. Issues is coming for only some pdf, when we convert from pdf to image using imagemagick. Issue is "Postscript delegate failed "